# woocommerce subscription API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using Woocomemrce REST API to connect with my site. Everything works fine when it comes to orders but it is not working with subscriptions. I have tried following code to get subscriptions but it is giving "Error: No route was found matching the URL and request method [rest_no_route]"

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.example.com',
    'ck_OUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
    'cs_OUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
    ]
);

try {
    print_r($woocommerce->get('orders')); //this works and fetch orders
    print_r($woocommerce->get('subscriptions')); //but this does not work
} catch (HttpClientException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
    echo $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
    echo $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
}
```

Can anyone help me sort out this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to the following it worked for me.

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.example.com',
    'ck_OUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
    'cs_OUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v1',
    ]
);
```